# Showing International Characters using Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Using Python v3 and Tkinter, I'm trying to read a text file that contains International characters and then display them on the screen (e.g. in a Menu) but the characters display wrongly.

a simple example of data in the text file is:-
Letzte VTR-Datei öffnen
(which I think is German for 'Open recent VTR file' - or something similar)

What I see is the ö character being replaced with something like a capital A with 2 dots on the top. Quite possible all the 'International' characters are replaced with that.

I tried adding encoding = "utf-8" to my source code but it didn't help.

e.g.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

encoding = "utf-8"

prompt={}
language_file = open("Control_lang_de.txt", "r")
for pmts in language_file:
    pmt = pmts.strip()
    x = pmt.split("=")
    key = x[0].strip()
    value = x[1].strip()
    prompt[key] = value

language_file.close()
# This reads a line with OpenRecentVTRFile=Letzte VTR-Datei öffnen
# So now have prompt[OpenRecentVTRFile] containing the text.

# Now add to the menu...
main_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=main_menu)
file_menu = Menu(main_menu, bd=2)
main_menu.add_cascade(label=prompt["OpenRecentVTRFile"], menu=file_menu)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve] that illustrates what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bryan. I have (hopefully) now done what you say.

Comment: This example would be better if it had a hard-coded string, unless you've determined that part of the problem is with reading the data from a file.

Comment: Setting an `encoding` variable in the Python script is not going to automatically set the encoding of the script, or anything in the script unless you use it as an argument to a function or something that requires such an argument. You have to set the encoding for your script using your editor/IDE.

Comment: Bryan - I'm not sure if the problem is with reading data from a file or it isn't. I would have hoped not. Perhaps someone will know if that does cause the problem I get. If it does, is there another way I should be reading the file?

Comment: Sylvester. Thanks for your reply. I am a bit new to this so I don't understand how IDE settings change how the data is displayed. I created the above example by using a basic text editor to create a .py file and then ran the script using python on a command prompt. Surely the way the script operates doesn't depend on it being run from an IDE set up in a particular way - or does it?

Comment: Well, the encoding is not specific to the IDE. All text files have encoding, and that can be _changed_ in a text editor. My point was simply that if you _want_ to change the encoding of a text file (like a `.py` file), you will have to do so using a text editor or an IDE. Try using a hard-coded string instead of loading the file (so `main_menu.add_cascade(label="Letzte VTR-Datei öffnen", menu=file_menu)` is what it would look like), and let us know if that fixes it. Note: If you want to tag someone in a comment, use `@` (for example, @SylvesterKruin).

Comment: @SylvesterKruin - Thanks for that. I tried it and it worked. Unfortunately that is not a solution for me as it is the data from a file I receive that I want to display. However, it would seem to mean that the data in the file is being changed somehow when it is read into Python.

Comment: Actually, it's good that it worked! Now we know that it could be the _file's_ (not the Python script's) encoding that's messing things up! What encoding does `Control_lang_de.txt` have? For example, if it's `utf-8` try using `language_file = open("Control_lang_de.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`. Usually, the text editor will say somewhere what the encoding is.

Comment: Thanks @SylvesterKruin. I tried that and it worked. I can now read the file in and get the data displayed correctly. I have tried French as well as German.

Comment: Glad to be of help! You should probably write an answer and accept it.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin - I'm happy to write an answer and accept it but I don't know how - yet. I'm learning how to do things on here.

Answer (score 1):

As the language file was encoded as utf-8, all I had to do was let the python open statement know about that. The solution turned out to be quite simple. I just needed to add
`encoding="utf-8"` to my open statement. When I changed it to
`language_file = open("Control_lang_de.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")` it worked as wanted.

Thanks to @SylvesterKruin for suggesting that to me.`